# WebSecurity and long IDs

Tags: asp.net-membership, security, webmatrix

I'm looking to use the long datatype (bigint) for various id values in a system and the current implementation for the WebSecurity class makes the assumption that the UserId is an int (smallint).

I'm considering downloading the source and editing it to use long data types instead.  Does anyone know if this has already been done?

TIA,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record I did end up porting the WebSecurity class source code into my source. Along with the associated Membership and Role provider source code and then edited to suit my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the UserId column in your table as a bigint if you like. You just have to tell the WebSecurity helper which column to use in the [InitializeDatabaseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method.

See this article on how to initialise the WebSecurity helper to use an existing database schema rather than allowing it to create its own: [THE most basic way to implement ASP.NET Razor security](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/displayblog.aspx?permalink=2240)

Comment: Hi Mike, this is indeed the way I have done it.  Using code-first my database is already using bigint for user id columns.  The problem arises when you start to use the WebSecurity class ...

    public static int CurrentUserId { get; }
    public static int GetUserId(string userName)
    public static int GetUserIdFromPasswordResetToken(string token)
    ...

Lots of systems you may wish to interact with use values that will exceed the int type ...

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Completely overlooked  that - you will have to create your own Membership Provider, override all the methods that refer to the UserId value being an int and dispense with the WebSecurity helper, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually I'm looking at the WebSecurity sourcecode at the moment and looking to build a custom version ... although I'm not completely convinced of this course of action yet :)